How easy to parse text file and delete segments with pattern
I try to find automated way to remove all those timestamps (2:00) from text. They have the same format but time is different from each time.
Is it possible to do using build in Word tools or DOS cmd ?
Thanks
This is sample of my input
 Hi ,bravo I can wait another day  (2:17) no more lonely  cars  (2:24) make 
it easy  (12:29)  hey luck you have all skills (13:33)    but it's OK

and wanted output
     Hi ,bravo I can wait another day   no more lonely  cars    make 
it easy    hey luck you have all skills     but it's OK

Thanks all

"Is it possible to do using buil[t] in Word tools or DOS cmd"? Can you explain what this has to do with [tag:ruby]? Also where does this input come from? Is it in a Word Document already? If so what format (.doc, .docx, .rtf, etc.)? Where do you want to output this to? All of these questions are germane to a proper response because I want to read from a word doc, remove the timestamps and save to a word doc is very different than I want to read from a text file remove these timestamps and output to STDOUT, or any other number of possible scenarios.

Use gsub function if you want to use ruby (ruby is tagged in this question)
.gsub(/\(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\)/, '')

Using MS-word, do the same thing. Use the regex \([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\)  and replace with nothing. Ctrl+H will give you find and replace box.
Using command line, it would be more convenient if you are using unix as it has sed
sed -E 's/\([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}\)//g' input.txt > output.txt will do the job.

updated my answer
